# Animate <ul> height when adding/removing floated <li>s not in the last row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a ul containing floated li elements of variable width that wrap around inside of a container into multiple rows. I am removing li elements from the ul, and would like the height of the container to animate to accommodate the potential removal of a row.

If I am removing from the last row, I am handling this by animating the height of the li to zero before removing it.

The problem arises when I remove an element from a row other than the last row, and it vacates enough space to pull all of the elements in the last row into the previous row. Since I'm not removing an element in the last row, my li height animation doesn't do anything, causing a jump in the height of the ul and container when that last row is vacated.

Is there a way to handle this or am I stuck with this jump in this special case?

```
For example:
```

https://jsfiddle.net/d4v5kyty/1/

EDIT: My solution is posted below and here is a working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/x3qt0m89/1/

Comment: Try adding a CSS transition to the `ul`

Comment: Please give us your current HTML and CSS so that we have a common starting point.

Comment: As @Jhecht says,  You should provide some code..

Comment: please provide a working code

Comment: @Jhecht apologies for the delay -- here is a fiddle modified from Lucas' answer below https://jsfiddle.net/d4v5kyty/1/ -- the issue being that the UL height jumps as LI elements move the previous row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using jQuery to solve this issue by applying inline styles to the container when the page loads, and then after appending to removing from the `ul` calculating its height and animating the container to the height of the `ul`, like so:

JS:

```
var container = $('.container');
container.attr('style','height:' + $('.container').css('height') + ';');

var animateContainer = function () {
  var ulHeight = $(container.find('ul')).css('height');
  container.animate({'height': ulHeight}, 250);
}

$('.js_removable').click(function () {
  $('.removable:not(.hidden)').first().addClass('hidden');
  setTimeout(function(){
    animateContainer();
  }, 1000)
});
```

because there is a delay in this happening, there is a time when the `ul` can be larger than the container (if appending to the `ul`). I had no problem with this, and just added `overflow: hidden;` to the container to clean up the effect.

Not sure if this is the best method, but it works well for my purposes.

Here is a working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/x3qt0m89/1/

Answer (score 1):

If you do not need to remove the elements from the `DOM` I would advise you to add a `transition` property to the LI elements and "remove" them by making them hidden on the canvas.

I've create [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/lucaslazaro/z3dnm4tr/) with an example that goes like this:

The normal HTML:

```
<!-- Just to remove the elements on the demo -->
<button class="js_removable">
 Remove last item
</button>

<ul class="transitionable">
  <li class="removable width-1">Content</li>
  <li class="removable width-2">Content</li>
  <li class="removable width-3">Content</li>
  <li class="removable width-4">Content</li>
  <li class="removable width-5">Content</li>
  <li class="removable width-3">Content</li>
  <li class="removable width-2">Content</li>
  <li class="removable width-5">Content</li>
</ul>
```

The CSS would include the floated elements with variable width and the ul as their parent:

```
.transitionable {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.removable {
  float: left;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.removable.hidden { 
  height: 0px;
  /* you can further remove it from the dom with the visibility property, this is just for demo reasons */
}

.width-1 {
  width: 25%;
  background-color: white;
}

/* ... rest of the variables widths */
```

And the JS to remove the elements:

```
$('.js_removable').click(function () {
    // Select only the not hidden elements .removable:not(.hidden) 
    $('.removable:not(.hidden)').last().addClass('hidden');
    // You can further remove it from DOM if necessary after the animation ends
});
```

Comment: Hi @lucas-lazaro, thank you very much for your answer -- this is a very close example but not quite what I meant. I updated your fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/d4v5kyty/1/  and while I don't necessarily need to remove elements from the DOM, the issue is more that elements other than the last will be removed, causing the UL to jump in height when the LI elements have more space to wrap around. I'd ideally like to transition that UL height, but I'm not sure if it's possible.

Comment: @yawnr I understand... Yeah that's a bit tricky since transitions on css only work between two defined values and because the parent can grow/shrink due it's children, I don't know any CSS-only approaches to this.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to really give a definitive answer since you didn't provide your code, but from what it sounds like, you're just missing some transitions. Try adding transition codes to the container and `<ul>`, and see what happens.